# How to access a new instantiated class method from another function in another class?

Tags: vb.net, class

I feel comfortable when instantiating a class, then using it within the same function, but now I need to instantiate a class from a toolbar button:

```
Dim pll As New Polyline()
Debug.WriteLine("TSB_Polyline_Click:: a new polyLine is born : " & pll.Count)
pll.AddPoint(0, 0)
```

And then I need to run the pll.AddPoint from my class method in another sub:

```
Public Sub MyEvent(sender as object, e as myEvent) Handles myEvent
Dim x as Double, y as Double
pll.AddPoint(x,y)
```

There I have my error (System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'), pll = Nothing (no error in my constructor, my class worked from the toolbar button_Click)

I tried to declare pll public and shared:

```
Public Shared pll As Polyline
```

And even to import it:

```
Imports oGIS.Polyline
```

Nothing works. My Class is instanciated in the first Sub (toolbar button), but somehow dies when leaving the Sub...

Is there any other solution that doing it using VB6 instead of VB.Net ?

I am a bit desesperate, I found no such topic anywhere on Google...

Comment: You should declare your `pll` object/variable in correct scope. If it should be accessible everywhere within single form, then it should be declared as Private variable at form level. If it is global over entire application (which is greatly not recommended), then you need VB.NET Module to achieve that - or if you have some main form always present, then it could be Friend (or even Public) property of that form (again not good solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing a partial look at your class would be something like this...

```
Public Class Polyline

    Public ReadOnly Property CountOfPoints As Integer
        Get
            Return ListOfPoints.Count
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Property ListOfPoints As New List(Of Point)

    Public Sub AddPoint(x As Integer, y As Integer)
        Dim p As New Point(x, y)
        ListOfPoints.Add(p)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Declare a class level (in this case the class is a Form) variable which can be seen and used by any method in your form.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private LocalPolyLine As Polyline
    'This is a local list, not part of the class
    'It is a list of the number of instances of the class you have created
    Private ListOfLines As New List(Of Polyline)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Pretend this is a button on your toolbar used to create a new line
        'Each time you click this button you have a completely new line with no points
        LocalPolyLine = New Polyline
        'If you want to keep track of how many lines you have...
        ListOfLines.Add(LocalPolyLine)
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddPoint(x As Integer, y As Integer)
        Debug.Print($"Number of Lines is {ListOfLines.Count}")
        Debug.Print($"Number of points on current line {LocalPolyLine.CountOfPoints}")
        LocalPolyLine.AddPoint(x, y)
        Debug.Print($"Number of points on current line {LocalPolyLine.CountOfPoints}")
    End Sub

'To see all the points on the line...

    Private Sub ViewPoints()
        For Each p In LocalPolyLine.ListOfPoints
            Debug.Print($"The coordinates of the point are {p.X},{p.Y}")
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Yes exactly, I used yesterday a form with a ListView to host all points sent by my EventHandler Sub, and I had no more issue. Sometimes one just need to reconsider the issue from a POO point of vue...

Comment: @Bob If my answer solved your problem, please accept it the clicking the check mark (tick mark)  to the left of the answer. Not only will this help future readers, it will earn you a couple of reputation points.

Comment: I thought I did but clicked the big arrow instead, sorry, I am a first time user. Done now, thank you for your time, all solved !

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access a variable in more than one method then it should be declared outside all of them. It should be `Private` if you don't need to access it outside the type it's declared in and it should only be `Shared` if you specifically need all instances of the class accessing the same object. In your case, `Private` and not `Shared` is the obvious choice:

```vb
Private pll As Polyline
```

You now set that field in the first method and get it in the second.